# Where to set defer on a struct(destructor) variable

Tags: go

I have a struct with a database session variable. Where should I set/call defer on this - like a constructor/destructor?

```
type MyType struct {
    session    *gocql.Session
}
```

I am attaching an instance of *gocql.Session and it should live as long as the struct.

```
func (this *myType) function_one_using_the_session(){}
func (this *myType) function_two_using_the_session(){}
```

I found [this](http://lk4d4.darth.io/posts/finalizers/): `runtime.SetFinalizer(a, func(a *Test) { fmt.Println("I AM DEAD") })`

I will probably do that or write my own `Close()` function.

This might do the trick - other comments is welcome?

I am trying to use only so many sessions. But should I defer the session in the following function:

```
    func GetSession() *gocql.Session {
        if cluster == nil {
            cluster = gocql.NewCluster("ip")
            cluster.Keyspace = "Keyspace"
            session, _ = cluster.CreateSession()
            return session
        } else {
            session, _ = cluster.CreateSession()
            // defer session.Close()
            }
    return session
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set/call defer" ? It doesn't make much sense. Maybe this link can clarify things for you: https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

Comment: can you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Don't use `SetFinalizer`, since that will close your session at an unpredictable time, or it may never close your session. From the documentation:  `typical usage scenario is to have one global session object to interact with the whole Cassandra cluster`

Comment: Hej JimB. Will you comment on the update that I made - using a GetSession() to return a session? Thanks, it sounds like you know this :-)

Comment: `defer` runs when the function returns. If you `defer` there, the session will be closed before it's ever been used; why are you trying to use `defer`? You can't use it if something exists outside the scope of a single function.

Comment: You are right, I will use it by passing around the session. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may compose your handlers using a context for setting the Cassandra session, use it and release afterwards, returning it to your pool of sessions.

Take a look [to this blog post](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access) about about how to organize your access to DB services.

Comment: Right on - thanks man